# Java Find Substring Inbetween Characters

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I am very stuck. I use this format to read a player's name in a string, like so:

```
"[PLAYER_yourname]"
```

I have tried for a few hours and can't figure out how to read only the part after the '_' and before the ']' to get there name.

Could I have some help? I played around with sub strings, splitting, some regex and no luck. Thanks! :)

BTW: This question is different, if I split by _ I don't know how to stop at the second bracket, as I have other string lines past the second bracket. Thanks!

Comment: use split method string.split("-")

Comment: Could u plz show ur effort?

Comment: you could use index of and then parse after n - 1

Comment: No, it's not that. If I split the string I go past the second braket, as I have other string's on the same line. How I do ONLY get the string after the '_' and before the ']'?

Comment: @SaketMittal that is not what he wants.

Comment: what is the exact input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
String s = "[PLAYER_yourname]";
String name = s.substring(s.indexOf("_") + 1, s.lastIndexOf("]"));
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not think of using that, because I didn't know how to use .indexOf or it's purpose. I appreciate it!

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, then you should make it as the right answer.

Comment: keep in mind this doesn't work if a user handle/player name includes a "]", you can use str.length - 1 to fix this. Also Zachary answered this before this answer, and is exact same...

Comment: @BrandonLing Or use ``lastIndexOf``

Answer (score 4):

You can use a substring. `int x = str.indexOf('_')` gives you the character where the '_' is found and `int y = str.lastIndexOF(']')` gives you the character where the ']' is found. Then you can do `str.substring(x + 1, y)` and that will give you the string from after the symbol until the end of the word, not including the closing bracket.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `regex` matcher functions you could do:

```
String s = "[PLAYER_yourname]";
String p = "\\[[A-Z]+_(.+)\\]";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(p);
Matcher m = r.matcher(s);

if (m.find( ))
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

**Result:**

```
yourname
```

**Explanation:**

```
\[ matches the character [ literally

[A-Z]+ match a single character (case sensitive + between one and unlimited times)

_ matches the character _ literally

1st Capturing group (.+) matches any character (except newline)

\] matches the character ] literally
```

Comment: I like this solution because it allows solving general cases.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses Java regex

```
String player = "[PLAYER_yourname]";
Pattern PLAYER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^\\[PLAYER_(.*?)]$");
Matcher matcher = PLAYER_PATTERN.matcher(player);
if (matcher.matches()) {
  System.out.println( matcher.group(1) );
}

// prints yourname
```

see [DEMO](http://ideone.com/5SDdP8)

[image]

Comment: Yes, it comes from [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dE6zA1/1). It does not have Java regex flavor but it still could be a helpful sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String s = "[PLAYER_yourname]";
        System.out.println(s.split("[_\\]]")[1]);
    }
```

> output: yourname

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?_([^\\]]+)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("[PLAYER_yourname]");
if (m.matches()) {
  String name = m.group(1);
  // name = "yourname"
}
```